# Decode html special chars and other elements

Tags: php, html, decode, html-entities

How to convert in PHP elements like `&agrave;` and `&#8217;` to a default utf8 character?

I try html_entity_decode with no success (i display some `?` in place of the `&agrave;` and `&#8217;` in place of `&#8217;`)

Answer (score 9):

You are having an encoding issue. `html_entity_decode` outputs iso-8859-1 by default. And by your `?` I assume you are using utf-8.

Try this: `html_entity_decode('&agrave;', ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')`

Answer (score -1):

```
html_entity_decode(utf8_decode('&#8217;'));
```

Comment: `utf8_decode('&#8217;')` does not change the string, your code is the same as `html_entity_decode('&#8217;')` - it will not work this way.